# Capybara can't find element on page on CI server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

So I have an integration test that works locally, but not on the CI server.

On the CI server it gets hung up on looking for an element on the page, and seemingly in rendering the page itself.

Any thoughts as to what the possible causes may be?

Here's the test (it's been failing on not being able to find the 'Get Individual Plan' link). Also, FWIW I'm using poltergeist as the js driver:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature "Submitting id theft form", type: :feature, js: true do
  scenario "with valid data" do
    visit '/recommends/id-theft-protection'

    click_link 'Get Individual Plan'

    within("#new_recommends_insurance_id_theft_protection_referral") do
      fill_in 'First Name', with: "test+#{Faker::Name.unique.first_name}"
      fill_in 'Last Name', with: 'Carpenter'
      fill_in 'Email Address', with: '*******@gmail.com'
      fill_in 'Phone Number', with: '***********'
      fill_in 'Street Address', with: '1 e'
      fill_in 'City', with: 'Lexington'
      select 'KY', from: 'State'
      fill_in 'ZIP Code', with: '40503'
      fill_in 'recommends_insurance_id_theft_protection_referral[birth_date]', with: '03/20/1989'
    end

    VCR.use_cassette('continue_to_payment') do
      click_button 'Continue to Payment'
    end

    expect(page).to have_content('Submit Payment')
  end
end
```

Backtrace:

```
09:57:17.781 bundle exec rspec spec --backtrace
09:57:17.781 
09:57:17.781 Randomized with seed 64563
09:57:17.782 
09:57:17.782 Progress: |============================================
09:57:17.782 
09:57:17.782   1) Submitting id theft form with valid data
09:57:17.782      Failure/Error: click_link 'Get Individual Plan'
09:57:17.782 
09:57:17.782      Capybara::ElementNotFound:
09:57:17.782        Unable to find visible link "Get Individual Plan"
09:57:17.782      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/capybara-2.17.0/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:314:in `block in synced_resolve'
09:57:17.782      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/capybara-2.17.0/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:85:in `synchronize'
09:57:17.782      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/capybara-2.17.0/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:302:in `synced_resolve'
09:57:17.782      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/capybara-2.17.0/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:37:in `find'
09:57:17.782      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/capybara-2.17.0/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb:43:in `click_link'
09:57:17.782      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/capybara-2.17.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:808:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Session>'
09:57:17.783      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/capybara-2.17.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:50:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
09:57:17.783      # ./spec/features/submitting_id_theft_form_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
09:57:17.783      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:254:in `instance_exec'
09:57:17.783      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:254:in `block in run'
09:57:17.783      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:500:in `block in with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
09:57:17.783      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:457:in `block in with_around_example_hooks'
09:57:17.783      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:466:in `block in run'
09:57:17.783      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:606:in `block in run_around_example_hooks_for'
09:57:17.783      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:342:in `call'
09:57:17.783      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-rails-3.7.2/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:127:in `block (2 levels) in <module:MinitestLifecycleAdapter>'
09:57:17.783      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:447:in `instance_exec'
09:57:17.783      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:447:in `instance_exec'
09:57:17.783      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:375:in `execute_with'
09:57:17.783      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:608:in `block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for'
09:57:17.784      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:342:in `call'
09:57:17.784      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:609:in `run_around_example_hooks_for'
09:57:17.784      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:466:in `run'
09:57:17.784      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:457:in `with_around_example_hooks'
09:57:17.784      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:500:in `with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
09:57:17.784      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:251:in `run'
09:57:17.784      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:628:in `block in run_examples'
09:57:17.784      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:624:in `map'
09:57:17.784      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:624:in `run_examples'
09:57:17.784      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:590:in `run'
09:57:17.784      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:118:in `block (3 levels) in run_specs'
09:57:17.784      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:118:in `map'
09:57:17.784      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:118:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
09:57:17.784      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1926:in `with_suite_hooks'
09:57:17.784      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:113:in `block in run_specs'
09:57:17.785      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:79:in `report'
09:57:17.785      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:112:in `run_specs'
09:57:17.785      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:87:in `run'
09:57:17.785      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
09:57:17.785      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
09:57:17.785      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
09:57:17.785      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/bin/rspec:22:in `load'
09:57:17.785      # /opt/go/ruby_cache_2.4.1_build/dr-recommends/ruby/2.4.0/bin/rspec:22:in `<top (required)>'
09:57:17.785      # /opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:75:in `load'
09:57:17.785      # /opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:75:in `kernel_load'
09:57:17.785      # /opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
09:57:17.785      # /opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:424:in `exec'
09:57:17.785      # /opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
09:57:17.785      # /opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
09:57:17.786      # /opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
09:57:17.786      # /opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
09:57:17.786      # /opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
09:57:17.786      # /opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
09:57:17.786      # /opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
09:57:17.786      # /opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:122:in `with_friendly_errors'
09:57:17.786      # /opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
09:57:17.786      # /opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
09:57:17.786      # /opt/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
09:57:17.786 
09:57:17.786 Progress: |====================================================================|
09:57:17.786 
09:57:17.786 Top 3 slowest examples (12.37 seconds, 99.6% of total time):
09:57:17.786   Submitting term life form with valid data
09:57:17.786     8.64 seconds ./spec/features/submitting_term_life_form_spec.rb:4
09:57:17.787   Submitting id theft form with valid data
09:57:17.787     2.55 seconds ./spec/features/submitting_id_theft_form_spec.rb:4
09:57:17.787   Submitting mortgage form with valid data
09:57:17.787     1.18 seconds ./spec/features/submitting_mortgage_form_spec.rb:4
09:57:17.787 
09:57:17.787 Top 3 slowest example groups:
09:57:17.787   Submitting term life form
09:57:17.787     8.64 seconds average (8.64 seconds / 1 example) ./spec/features/submitting_term_life_form_spec.rb:3
09:57:17.787   Submitting id theft form
09:57:17.787     2.59 seconds average (2.59 seconds / 1 example) ./spec/features/submitting_id_theft_form_spec.rb:3
09:57:17.787   Submitting mortgage form
09:57:17.787     1.18 seconds average (1.18 seconds / 1 example) ./spec/features/submitting_mortgage_form_spec.rb:3
09:57:17.787 
09:57:17.787 Finished in 12.42 seconds (files took 3.82 seconds to load)
09:57:17.788 3 examples, 1 failure
09:57:17.788 
09:57:17.788 Failed examples:
09:57:17.788 
09:57:17.788 rspec ./spec/features/submitting_id_theft_form_spec.rb:4 # Submitting id theft form with valid data
09:57:17.788 
09:57:17.788 Randomized with seed 64563
```

Comment: Are the versions of PhantomJS installed on both machines the same?  Other than that, check for JS errors (make sure `js_errors` is true in your Poltergeist configuration) since a big difference between the dev and test environments is asset concatenation where a JS error that doesn't affect dev can prevent the entire JS file from loading in the test environment.  Also, please add the full error (with stacktrace) you get to your question.

Comment: Not 100% on the versions of Phantom, but I can most definitely get back to you tomorrow on that. I definitely do have `js_errors` set to `false`, so maybe that's an area to work through as well, (locally I just get errors I can ignore, but maybe something's coming up in test that would prevent the page from rendering?) Also, stack trace added and thanks a ton for your help! @ThomasWalpole

Comment: If it's not a JS error causing stuff on the page not to load, then check the capitalization of the link text matches what's actually shown on the page - (`save_and_open_screenshot` can help with that before the `click_link`, possibly with a few second sleep before it to ensure the page has actually loaded)